# Why bootstrap not working in MS Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, twitter-bootstrap

A newly installed visual studio 2010. Then i tried to add bootstrap for better design but its not working

Here is my code

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="mySample.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        <link href="contents/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="contents/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Job Order System</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Closed Request</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-2.1.0.min.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/script/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It only display a normal list

Please help me solving this kind of problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 potential problems:

1. You're using a relative URI in the `<link />` elements, this won't be a problem if every page is in the root of your website, but it's good practice to make these Application-root-relative URIs. Add `runat="server"` to the element and begin the `href` with `~/` and ASP.NET will automatically give it a correct URI
2. You've put the `<link />` inside `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder` elements, which means they're the "default content" of the placeholders. If any of your pages set content for that placeholder then the default content (i.e. your bootstrap links) will be removed.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I got it.. Thanks for the help.. and the problem is in number 2.. :-) Thank you so much